# Compare values from 2 tables and produce a new table with the differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a way in SQL Server (script) to:

1. Given 2 tables, with identical column structure
2. Filled with rows sharing an identical key
3. But with different values in one of the columns (INTEGER)
4. Find rows with the matching key in both tables and compare them to produce a new row. in a different table, with the exact same matching values in the rest of the columns and the difference in value between the only non-matching column.

Ex. It's the same db in 4 versions, every new iteration accumulating the values of the previous version, what I'm trying to achieve is a new db with the difference (like in db1 the amount of apples sold is 5, and in db2 the amount of apples sold is 20, I need a new row in a new table with a value of 15).

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result table - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sounds like a simple join on the foreign keys and doing the calculation on the integer field to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please make an attempt to do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    theKey int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    someInt int
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
    theKey int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    otherInt int
)

CREATE TABLE output (
    theKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    someInt int,
    otherInt int,
    valueDifference int
)

INSERT INTO output ( theKey, someInt, otherInt, valueDifference )
SELECT
    foo.theKey,
    foo.someInt,
    bar.otherInt,
    foo.someInt - bar.otherInt AS valueDifference
FROM
    foo
    INNER JOIN bar ON foo.theKey = bar.theKey
```